# Сортировка по кастомному атрибуту в Yii2

Tags: yii2, сортировка, activerecord, gridview

Есть виджет GridView на индексной странице. Есть кастомный атрибут, выводящий значение в зависимости от результата функции. Этот атрибут прописан в модели как публичное свойство, но в гриде отображается черным без ссылки, то есть сортировка по нему невозможна.

Способы, предложенные в других похожих темах, почему-то не помогли.

Код в model

```
public $STATUS;
public const SENT = 'Отправлен';
public const DRAFT = 'Черновик';
```

Код в view

```
        [
            'attribute' => 'STATUS',
            'value' => function($model) {
                if (Notifications::isNotificationSended($model->ID)) {
                    $model->STATUS = Notifications::SENT;
                }
                else {
                    $model->STATUS = Notifications::DRAFT;
                }
                return $model->STATUS;  
            }           
        ],
```

Если указать в search model (как в этой теме - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27936787/how-i-do-custom-yii2-gridview-sort)

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'sort' => ['attributes' => ['STATUS']],
       ]);
```

то ругается, что нет такого атрибута и выводит SQL ошибку.

Как я понял, я неправильно указываю атрибут? Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: попробуйте сделать свойство с всё маленькими буквами и здесь `['attributes' => ['STATUS']],`  тоже.........ещё возможно его надо добавить в rules в модели `[['status'], 'safe']`

Comment: Попробовал, не помогло, но похоже дело было в другом. Выше в коде я не указал еще одну строку, то есть изначально в search model было так

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
   'sort' => [
    'defaultOrder' => ['ID'=>SORT_DESC],
    'attributes' => ['STATUS'],
   ]
        ]);

и, видимо свой-во default_order перебивало св-во attributes. Правда вылезли другие ошибки, но, думаю, это уже легче исправить, все равно спасибо за отклик. Отпишусь, как окончательно разберусь.